# Plotting border of masked array with plt.imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow, masked-array

Actually plotting this image using `plt.imshow` and `np.masked` to plot the figure in blue. I would like to remove the inner part of the figure and just leaving the border. Tried with `fill=False` but that's not an arg for `plt.imshow`.

Code:

```
#img comes from a raster using GDAL

img = np.dstack((band1, band2, band3))
max = img.max()
img = img / max
one = f.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
one.set_title('Polygon ID: '+index)
plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
plt.imshow(masked_polygon, 'jet', interpolation='none', alpha=0.3)
plt.axis('off')
```

Result of plot:

[image: Resulting plot]